# Некорректный pts при декодировании видеопотока

Tags: c++, c, видео, ffmpeg, libav

Пробовал запускать разные видосы для тестирования вывода. И вот наткнулся на такой `avi`-контейнер, который выдаёт невалидный `pts`. Он, через кадр, равен либо номеру кадра, либо просто мусорному числу.

При этом `avformat_find_stream_info` и последующий `av_dump_format` находит и выводит средний FPS. Понятно, что он, видимо, ориентируется просто по общей продолжительности потока и примерному количеству кадров. Но, скажем, тот же **VLC Player** видос то проигрывает на нормальой скорости.

**Вопрос:** Это нормальная ситуация? Я должен ориентироваться на средний FPS, если кадры имеют некорректный `pts`? И как тогда лучше определить, что у потока невалидные `pts`?

Вот логи:

```
Frame: B (144), pts 144, dts 144, keyframe 0, coded 144, display 0
PixFmt: from yuv420p to rgb24       FPS: cur 59.94, avg 64.81
Packet: buf 0x56425ca77200, pts 144, dts 144, data 0x56425cab9a80, size 7485, dur 1, pos 1112544
Original video frame
    uint8_t* data[]:    0x56425c70c740, 0x56425c7547c0, 0x56425c766840, (nil), (nil), (nil), (nil), (nil)
    int linesize[]:     768, 384, 384, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Converted video frame
    uint8_t* data[]:    0x7fe1ed9dd040, (nil), (nil), (nil), (nil), (nil), (nil), (nil)
    int linesize[]:     2112, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0

Frame: P (145), pts -9223372036854775808, dts 145, keyframe 0, coded 143, display 0
PixFmt: from yuv420p to rgb24       FPS: cur 59.94, avg 64.81
Packet: buf 0x56425caa61c0, pts -9223372036854775808, dts 145, data 0x56425cabc4c0, size 43497, dur 1, pos 1122382
Original video frame
    uint8_t* data[]:    0x56425c63fa40, 0x56425c687ac0, 0x56425c699b40, (nil), (nil), (nil), (nil), (nil)
    int linesize[]:     768, 384, 384, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
Converted video frame
    uint8_t* data[]:    0x7fe1ed9dd040, (nil), (nil), (nil), (nil), (nil), (nil), (nil)
    int linesize[]:     2112, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0
```

**PS:** В логах FPS выдаёт просто на максимальной скорости, с которой его декодирует и выводит через `SDL`.

**PPS:** И ещё вопрос. А бывают видосы со значительно неравномерным  выводом кадров. Скажем, если на одном  интервале будет 25 FPS, а на другом 50 FPS.

Comment: так вроде pts и fps никак не связаны. pts нужны только для синхронизации

Comment: @SergeyTatarincev, PTS нужен для вывода кадра в заданный момент времени, значит они c FPS связаны. FPS влияет на PTS, чем чаще кадры, тем меньше `AVRational`.

Comment: `-9223372036854775808` соответствует константе [`AV_NOPTS_VALUE`](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/group__lavu__time.html#ga2eaefe702f95f619ea6f2d08afa01be1), а вообще приводите media info файла, чтобы узнать почему он возникает, следует смотреть в конкретный кодек. Частота кадров бывает и переменная (VFR).

Comment: @user7860670, в общем-то, это не ошибка, это просто особенность контейнера (не кодека). В описании к константе написано: *Usually reported by demuxer that work on containers that do not provide either pts or dts*. И я нашёл примеры кода, где происходит проверка при декодировании. Но не совсем понятно пока, что с этим дальше делать. Будем разбираться.